Captured Image appears to be streched width wise after capturing it through camera


const imageWidth = 320;

const imageHeigth = 240;

const imageHeigthOfUploadImage = 423;



$(function () {

    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size

    //var jcrop_api;

    var boundx, boundy;

    let cropper;



    //#region WebCam

    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.

    let video = document.getElementById('video');





    // Elements for taking the snapshot

    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');



    // Trigger photo take

    document.getElementById("btnCapture").addEventListener("click", function () {

        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeigth);



        //Set the canvas to Image1

        $("#Image1")[0].src = canvas.toDataURL();



        //Show the respective controls

        $("#Image1").show();

        $("#canvas").hide();

        $('#btnSave').show();

        $('#btnCrop').show();

        $('#btnClear').show();



        /*//Destroy Jcrop if it is existed

        if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {

            jcrop_api.destroy();

            jcrop_api = null;

        }*/



        //Destroy cropperjs if it is existed

        if (cropper) {

            cropper.destroy();

        }



        /*//Jcrop for Webcamera

        $('#Image1').Jcrop({

            boxWidth: imageWidth,   //Maximum width you want for your bigger images

            boxHeight: imageHeigth,  //Maximum Height for your bigger images

            onChange: updateCoords,

            onSelect: updateCoords

        },

            function () {

                // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size

                var bounds = this.getBounds();

                boundx = bounds[0];

                boundy = bounds[1];

                // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable

                jcrop_api = this;

                $("#canvas").hide();

            });*/



        //cropperjs for Webcamera

        cropper = new Cropper($('#Image1')[0], {

            viewMode: 1,

            //aspectRatio: imageWidth / imageHeigth,

            crop(event) {

                $('#x').val(event.detail.x);

                $('#y').val(event.detail.y);

                $('#w').val(event.detail.width);

                $('#h').val(event.detail.height);

            },

        });

    });



    //#endregion WebCam



    //#region FileUpload, Resize & Jcrop

    $('#image_file').change(function (event) {

        // get selected file

        var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

        // preview element

        var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

        // to make the experience better

        $('#preview').hide();



        // prepare HTML5 FileReader

        var oReader = new FileReader();

        oReader.onload = function (e) {

            // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image

            oImage.src = e.target.result;

            oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler

                $('#Image1').attr("src", e.target.result);



                //#region Resize logic

                var img = document.createElement("img");

                img.src = e.target.result;

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

                //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);



                var MAX_WIDTH = imageWidth;

                var MAX_HEIGHT = imageHeigthOfUploadImage;

                var width = img.width;

                var height = img.height;



                if (width > height) {

                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {

                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;

                        width = MAX_WIDTH;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {

                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;

                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;

                    }

                }



                canvas.width = width;

                canvas.height = height;

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");



                //Set the resized image to the Image control

                document.getElementById('Image1').src = dataurl;



                //Show the respective controls

                $('#preview').hide();

                $('#btnSave').show();

                $('#btnCrop').show();

                $('#btnClear').show();



                //Destroy Jcrop if it is existed

                /*if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {

                    jcrop_api.destroy();

                    jcrop_api = null;

                    //$('#preview').width(oImage.naturalWidth);

                    //$('#preview').height(oImage.naturalHeight);

                }*/

                //Destroy Cropper if it is existed

                if (cropper) {

                    cropper.destroy();

                }



                //Jcrop for UploadFile

                /*$('#Image1').Jcrop({

                    boxWidth: imageWidth,   //Maximum width you want for your bigger images

                    boxHeight: imageHeigthOfUploadImage,  //Maximum Height for your bigger images

                    onChange: updateCoords,

                    onSelect: updateCoords

                }, function () {

                    // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size

                    var bounds = this.getBounds();

                    boundx = bounds[0];

                    boundy = bounds[1];

                    // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable

                    jcrop_api = this;

                    $("#canvas").hide();

                });*/

                //Cropper for UploadFile

                cropper = new Cropper($('#Image1')[0], {

                    viewMode: 1,

                    //aspectRatio: width / height,

                    crop(event) {

                        $('#x').val(event.detail.x);

                        $('#y').val(event.detail.y);

                        $('#w').val(event.detail.width);

                        $('#h').val(event.detail.height);

                    },

                });

            };

        };

        // read selected file as DataURL

        oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);

    });



    //#endregion FileUpload, Resize & Jcrop



    $('#btnCrop').click(function () {

        //Get the Coords from the Hidden controls

        var x1 = $('#x').val();

        var y1 = $('#y').val();

        var width = $('#w').val();

        var height = $('#h').val();

        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.height = height;

        canvas.width = width;



        let image = document.createElement('img');

        image.onload = function () {

            //Draw the image with the coords defined by the user

            context.drawImage(image, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);



            //Set the resized image to the Image control

            $('#imgCropped').val(canvas.toDataURL());

            $("#capturedImage")[0].src = canvas.toDataURL();



            //Needed at the server side to get the image value

            document.getElementById("<%=ImgExSrc.ClientID%>").value = canvas.toDataURL();



            //Show the respective controls

            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;

            $('#btnSubmit').show();

            $('#lblTermsConditions').show();

            $('#chkApprove').show();



            //Reset the canvas height & width

            console.log('before:' + canvas.height + '-' + canvas.width);

            canvas.height = imageHeigth;

            canvas.width = imageWidth;

            console.log('after:' + canvas.height + '-' + canvas.width);

        };

        //image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        image.src = $('#Image1').attr("src");

        $("#canvas").hide();



        image.onerror = function () {

            alert("Error occurred while loading image");

        };

    });



    $('#btnSave').click(function () {

        $("#capturedImage")[0].src = $('#Image1').attr("src");

        document.getElementById("<%=ImgExSrc.ClientID%>").value = $('#Image1').attr("src");

        $('#btnSubmit').show();

        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;

        document.getElementById("chkApprove").checked = false

        $('#lblTermsConditions').show();

        $('#chkApprove').show();

    });



    $('#btnClear').click(function () {

        Clear();

    });



    $('.nav-link').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var activeHref = $(".nav-link.active").attr("href");

        if (activeHref != "#menu1") {

            document.getElementById("btnSetDataToDelete").click();

        }

    })

});



function GetAccessToCamera() {

    let video = document.getElementById('video');



    // Get access to the camera!

    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

        // Not adding { audio: true } since we only want video now

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, width: imageWidth, heigth: imageHeigth }).then(function (stream) {

            //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            video.srcObject = stream;

            video.play();

        });

    }

}



function StopCamera() {

    try {

        let video = document.getElementById('video');

        var stream = video.srcObject;

        var tracks = stream.getTracks();



        for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {

            var track = tracks[i];

            track.stop();

        }



        video.srcObject = null;

    } catch { }

}



function updateCoords(c) {

    $('#x').val(c.x); $('#y').val(c.y); $('#w').val(c.w); $('#h').val(c.h); $('#btnCrop').show(); $('#btnClear').show();

};



function isEmpty(obj) {

    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;

}



function Clear() {

    $('#Image1').attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==');

    $("div.jcrop-holder").remove();

    $("div.jcrop-tracker").remove();

    $('#btnSave').hide();

    $('#btnCrop').hide();

    $('#btnClear').hide();

}



function UserException(message) {

    alert(message);

    console.log(message);

}



function ToggleCamera() {

    if ($("#video").hasClass("HideCamera")) {

        $("#video").removeClass("HideCamera")

        GetAccessToCamera();

    }

    else {

        $("#video").addClass("HideCamera");

        StopCamera();

    }

}

<div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

</div>



<div class="container" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h5 style="float: right;">

            <asp:Label ID="lblLoggedInUser" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h5>

        <h4>

            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle_H" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, First_Page_Title_H1 %>"></asp:Label></h4>



        <p>

            <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblTitle_Desc" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, First_Page_Title_Description %>"></asp:Label>--%>

        </p>

    </div>



    <!-- Nav tabs -->

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblUploadPhoto" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, lblUploadPhoto %>"></asp:Label>

                    </a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblResetPhoto" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, lblResetPhoto %>"></asp:Label></a>

                </li>

            </ul>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSetDataToDelete" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnSetDataToDelete_Click" Style="display: none;" />

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>



    <!-- Tab panes -->

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active">

            <br />

            <h3>

                <asp:Label ID="lblUploadPhoto1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, lblUploadPhoto %>"></asp:Label></h3>

            <br />

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 center" style="background-color: lavender;">

                    <div class="center">

                        <p>

                            <b>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblLiveCamera" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, lblLiveCamera %>"></asp:Label></b>

                        </p>

                        <label class="switch">

                            <input type="checkbox" />

                            <span class="slider round" onclick="ToggleCamera();"></span>

                        </label>

                        <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay class="HideCamera"></video>

                        <br />

                        <asp:Button ID="btnCapture" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, btnCapture %>" />

                        <br />

                        <br />

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 center" style="background-color: orange;">

                    <div class="center">

                        <p>

                            <b>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblUploadFile" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, lblUploadFile %>"></asp:Label></b>

                        </p>

                        <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />

                        <br />

                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <table class="table" border="0">

                        <tbody>

                            <tr>

                                <td>

                                    <img id="preview" />

                                    <img id="Image1" src="" style="display: block" />

                                    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>

                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

As you can see in the attached screenshot, after I use the Live Camera and Capture an image, the image appears to be stretched widthwise in the class="col-md-4 center". This happens only while using the website on mobiles. I want that the image as it is captured in the class="col-md-4 center". This issue is only there on mobiles, what changes should I make to solve it?
